# In Typescript should you use type assertion when taking a record from a dictionary that could have been undefined?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, assertion

Dictionaries are often used to efficiently test for the presence of an element by a string identifier. If the result is `undefined` it does not exist. A memory cache is a good example:

```
/**
 * Cache of normalized data
 */
export interface IDataNormalizationsCache
  extends Record<NormalizationMethod, ILeanTrainingData | undefined> {}

/**
 * A dictionary which caches all performed varieties of data normalizations.
 */
const dataNormalizations: IDataNormalizationsCache = {
  [NormalizationMethod.log]: undefined
}
```

We can then retrieve this data from cache:

```
// Retrieve from cache
if (typeof dataNormalizations[method] !== 'undefined') {
  return dataNormalizations[method]
}
```

However, even though `dataNormalizations[method]` is guaranteed to be defined at this point, and therefore be of type `ILeanTrainingData`, Typescript throws a compilation error:

```
[ts]
Type 'ILeanTrainingData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ILeanTrainingData'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ILeanTrainingData'.
```

Why is the compiler not identifying the `typeof undefined` test?

Is there a better way to do this than to use type assertion such as:

```
// Retrieve from cache
if (typeof dataNormalizations[method] !== 'undefined') {
  return dataNormalizations[method] as ILeanTrainingData
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sad consequence of [an outstanding issue in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) whereby property access via bracket notation does not trigger type guarding the way it does with dot notation. Apparently it is straightforward to add the check for bracket notation to the compiler, but it results in significantly longer compile times.

I assume you don't know at compile time the actual string literal for the property name... otherwise I'd suggest to use dot notation:

```
if (typeof dataNormalizations.knownMethod !== 'undefined') {
  return dataNormalizations.knownMethod; // works
}
```

and it would work.  But you probably can't do that.  The better workaround in this case would be to assign the property to a new variable:

```
const dataNormalizationsMethod = dataNormalizations[method];
if (typeof dataNormalizationsMethod !== 'undefined') {
  return dataNormalizationsMethod; // works
}
```

which also allows type guarding to work, since it's no longer doing property access.

And your type assertion is also fine, in my opinion.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Great answer and interesting workaround. The workaround however is not ideal when trying to set a property, which is often the case when working with caches. E.g.: `dataNormalizations[method] = normalize(rawData); return dataNormalizations[method]` still gives a compilation error and you cannot do `let cached = dataNormalizations[method]; cached = normalize(rawData); return cached;` because this would not update the dictionary

Comment: You could do `let cached = dataNormalizations[method] = normalize(rawData); return cached;` or just `return (dataNormalizations[method] = normalize(rawData));`.